# Error while accessing Azure Functions app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure App deployed. This app is tested locally (in VS Code) & deployed via Azure Devops (using Azure Pipeline). It successfully runs in local environment while testing. It also has deployment slots enabled.

Bindings used in this Azure Functions are ServiceBus (trigger) and Storage (output). Also the Function App has a package.json in the root of the project for installing the dependencies (as per this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#dependency-management)).

When accessing the app in Azure portal I get this error:

[image]

When I access the staging slot, I get this error(Error about bindings):

[image]

Errors on staging are related to binding errors, but looking at this **Integrate** page for staging slot it seems they are recognized correctly.

[image]

How can I get rid of these errors? What am I missing? Am I missing some extensions of these bindings. And why the error on production slot has the message **An error has occurred.** with no more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For V2 function you need to register service bus extension using CLI:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#local-development-azure-functions-core-tools

Comment: Hi, didn't knew that extensions have to be installed manually when deploying through deployment source. That doc doesn't directly answers my question, but provides a link to a different one, which describes how to install extension manually.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/install-update-binding-extensions-manual